Air resistance required to spin thin flat upright square
I need to spin a thin flat square, about 15.36 cm side length, 1.6 mm thickness, and I am trying to figure out how powerful of a motor I am going to need but I am unsure how to account for the force due to air resistance.  The square will be spun upright on its center.  Mass is negligible

